Почему изменяется размер scrollbar'a вместе с фреймом
Пишу программу, в которой нужно разделить окно на две части. Сделал с одной стороны scrollbar, а по центру хочу провести вертикальную линию. Однако для frame_line не работает fill=tk.Y, а если хочу задать height=, то меняется высота scrollbar. И можете написать, как настроить "ползунок" (забиндить колесико мыши, другие нужные настройки)?
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.title('Сохранятель')
window.geometry('800x500')
window.resizable(False, False)

frame_line = tk.Frame(master=window, width=1, bg='black')
frame_line.pack(fill=tk.Y)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master=window, orient=VERTICAL, width=16)
scrollbar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT)

window.mainloop()


Используйте grid. Либо добавьте два фрейма для левой и правой части, внутри них все содержимое размещайте.
